# VBA Param List in ReDim and Param List as index of array

Tags: vba, list

I'm building a module with the purpose to ease the 'Redim' of a multidimentionnal array.

The main function is IncDimension which take an array, the dimension you want to redefine and the number of place to add or remove.

```
Public sub main()
 Dim v as variant

 ReDim a (1 to 3, 1 to 4, 1 to 5)
 Call IncDimension(a, 1, 5)
 'Before a (1 to 3, 1 to 4, 1 to 5)
 'After  a (1 to 8, 1 to 4, 1 to 5)
End sub
```

It works fine when the number of dimension is between 1 and 9 because I made sure every case were implemented. BUT let's say I might need to work with an array with more than 9 dimensions, my module is useless.

There are 2 places where I had to use a Select Case based on the number of dimension : 
When I want to 'Redim' the array

```
    Select Case nbDimension
    Case 1
        ReDim Preserve arr( _
        LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) + i)
    Case 2
        ReDim Preserve arr( _
        LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), _
        LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) + i)
    Case 3
        ReDim Preserve arr( _
        LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1), _
        LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), _
        LBound(arr, 3) To UBound(arr, 3) + i)
'etc.
```

When I want to move value in the temp array (tbl)

```
    Select Case nbDimension
    Case 2
        tbl(lstTransferts(1), lstTransferts(2)) = arr(lstIndex(1), lstIndex(2))
    Case 3
        tbl(lstTransferts(1), lstTransferts(2), lstTransferts(3)) = arr(lstIndex(1), lstIndex(2), lstIndex(3))
'etc.
```

So, **is there a way to use a list of value in ReDim Preserve** and **is there a way to use a list of index when accessing an array**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dynamically created a module based on the number of dimensions.

```
Private Sub creerModuleSelonDimension(ByRef tbl As Variant, ByRef arr As Variant, ByRef lstDimensions As Variant)
Dim vbComp As Object
Dim useReDim As String
Dim dynamicReDim As String
Dim app As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create the ReDim statement dynamically
dynamicReDim = "ReDim tbl( _" & vbNewLine
For i = LBound(lstDimensions) To UBound(lstDimensions)
    dynamicReDim = dynamicReDim + "LBound(arr, lstDimensions(" & i & ")) to UBound(arr, lstDimensions(" & i & ")), _ " & vbNewLine
Next i
dynamicReDim = Left(dynamicReDim, Len(dynamicReDim) - 6) & " _ " & vbNewLine & ")"

'Create the sub
useReDim = "Public Sub useReDim(ByRef tbl as Variant, ByRef arr as Variant, ByRef lstDimensions as variant)" & vbNewLine & dynamicReDim & vbNewLine & "End Sub"

'Create a new module and add the sub in it
Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString useReDim

'Allow the use of ByRef variables in Application.Run
Set app = Application

'Run useReDim with ByRef variables
i = app.Run(vbComp.Name & ".useReDim", tbl, arr, lstDimensions)

'Delete the new module
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop this... This doesn't make sense. In first place, why do you need such a multi dimensional array? I never used more than 2 dimensions, and I didn't find any use for larger variants. This clearly seems like a request for a bad solution to an ill-posed problem. What's your real problem?

Comment: I do use 9D arrays when I have to deal with massive amount of data for analytic purpose. As I wrote, the module works the way it should for 1D to 9D arrays. My 'real problem', as I wrote before, is that I would have to rewrite the module if I use bigger array and yes, it might happen, since VBA arrays can be initialised with 60 000 dimensions or so.

Comment: Just use a dictionnary, with Keys as dimensions, containing your arrays, or other dictionaries.  You cannot 'variable-ize' the 'ReDim' since it's a statement, not a function